# Looking for Correct Java REGEX for this kind of payload

Tags: java, regex

I have following two different payloads where I am trying to Write Java Regex:

**Input Payload 1**

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*EXDO           *ZZ*047336389      *150327*1007*U*00401*900063730*0*P*>~
GS*QM*EXDO*047336389*20150327*1007*900063730*X*004010~
ST*214*900063730~
B10*326GENT15173**EXDO~
L11*019*TN~
```

**Input Payload 2**

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *02*HJBT           *01*047336389      *140103*1751*U*00401*000012003*0*P*>\
GS*QM*HJBT*047336389*20140103*1751*12003*X*004010\
ST*214*0001\
B10*117094*B065199*HJBT\
N1*SH*INTEVA PRODUCTS LLC-\
```

I have following REGEX:

```
.*(ST\*214|ST\*210).*
```

I tried to evaluate the REGEX on this URL http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

I see matches() as NO for 1st Payload and matches() as YES for 2nd Payload. I am looking for Updated REGEX which actually works for BOTH conditions here.

My Purpose here to validate payload information just like String contains method can do it using following approach.

```
payload.toString().contains('ST*214') || payload.toString().contains('ST*210').
```

I want to use regex instead of string.contains here.

Comment: Can you format your payload properly? It's hard to figure out any pattern from there.

Comment: what are you trying to validate? can you give invalid input?

Comment: @RohitJain I updated the payload information and you can try this payload on given URL and you will see the result.

Comment: Why should it not match the second one? Both provided payloads contain `ST*214`?

Comment: The pattern as shown doesn't match either string. If the asterisk is made literal by prefixing with `\` the pattern matches both strings.

Comment: What cases shouldn't match? We have a positive but no negative examples.

Comment: It should match it. If payload contains either of these 2 string "ST*214" OR "ST*210"

Comment: Neighter of the two payloads pasted from the question to regexplanet match the provided pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"(?s).*(ST\\*214|ST\\*210).*"
```

In Java you need to enable DOTALL mode (to make . match with line terminators too). This can be done by including (?s) modifier. You had match only in this ST*214*900063730~ particular part of first string.

[image: test]

Answer (score -1):

I think you try to match the wildcard character `'*'` so you should use backslashes :

```
.*(ST\*214|ST\*210).*
```

or

```
.*ST\*(214|210).*
```

or

```
.*ST\*21(4|0).*
```

or

```
.*ST\*21[40].*
```

Are the linefeed part of your payload or just some formatting ?

Comment: Please try out your regex with 2 different payload i provided on this URL  [ http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html] matches() show as NO for both payloads.

Comment: Ok, but in the colum "find()", you'll see "YES".  To make the entire payload to match, you'll have to do as in Juris Lacis answer and surround the pattern with `.*` ie : `.*(ST\*214|ST\*210).*`.  I'll update my answer

Comment: yes that's right it shows YES for find() method. but i am looking for solution where i am using Mule regex() function and it is only implemented using matches() option here.

Answer (score -1):

use the following regexp:
".*(ST\*214|ST\*210).*"
Have tested your two strings with following code:

```
public class RegTest {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String test1 = "ISA*00* 00 ZZEXDO *ZZ*047336389*150414*1108*U*00401*979863647*0*P*>~ GSQMEXDO*047336389*20150414*1108*979863647*X*004010~ ST*214*979863647~ B10*186143**EXDO~";
    String test2 = "ISA*00* 00 *02*HJBT *01*047336389*140103*1751*U*00401*000012003*0*P*>\\GSQMHJBT*047336389*20140103*1751*12003*X*004010\\ST*214*0001\\B10*117094*B065199*HJBT\\N1*SH*INTEVA PRODUCTS LLC-\\";
    if (test1.matches(".*(ST\\*214|ST\\*210).*")) {
        System.out.println("String1 matches");
    }
    if (test2.matches(".*(ST\\*214|ST\\*210).*")) {
        System.out.println("String2 matches");
    }
}
```

}

just small fix, regexp in comment lost two '\' characters. You can use the regexp from code.

Comment: Where does your answer prove that `ST*210` is matched?

Comment: Both strings matches ST*214, ST*210 are not given, but if you change ST*214 to ST*210 string will match too.

Comment: @JurisLacis if you try to use my payload copy and paste it to Given URL and use your REGEX matches shows YES for 2nd Payload but it shows NO for 1st Payload. Have you tried it ?

Comment: @devanand, when i click on this link I have 404 response :/, I have tested on my test environment, both strings are matched. I have changed one string to ST*213 and have got single string matched. I have a bit edited second string, you have some backslashes and I had to escape them.

Comment: Something is wrong there or I am Java-like escaping backslashes and reserved characters, you told you are using Java, on Java it is working fine for me ;)